# how to handle a post collection zf2 rest

Tags: php, rest, zend-framework2

Everywhere I read that the POST method in ZF2 RestController is builded to support create Collections of data

But I can't find a tutorial on internet that shows a create collection method, I only found alone enitity been created in POST create method.

So, how handle the POST (create) method to accept only one Entity post or a Collection of Entities

sorry for my English, I'm Brazilian

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about the implementation of this controller https://github.com/zendframework/zend-mvc/blob/master/src/Controller/AbstractRestfulController.php

Basically, it is up to you how you will implement the `create()` method. You can either support multiple record creation or not. You have all the freedom how you will process the payload data.